# Unit-test for reading data from a usb bulk transfer packet

Tags: android, unit-testing, usb

I have developed an app that acts as a usb host reading bulk transfer packets from a usb accessory

If I want to develop unit-tests for that part of the app, is there any way to mock a usb connection and incoming data packets?

It would be very useful to automate testing of the relevant code without actually having to plug in the accessory